# How do I convert a file stream to a data URI in Python?

Tags: python, stream, filestream, data-uri

I have a file stream of an image in Python:

```
\x89PNG\r\n\x1a\n\x00\x00\x00\rIHDR\x00\x00\x04\x87...
```

How do I convert this to a [data URI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme#HTML)?

```
'data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAU...'
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Encode it in base64, then remove the newlines.

```
>>> '\x89PNG\r\n\x1a\n\x00\x00\x00\rIHDR\x00\x00\x04\x87...'.encode('base64').replace('\n', '')
'iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAABI....'
```

Comment: I didn't know you could encode that way, I always thought you needed the `base64` module

Comment: Python has quite a few non-text [encodings](http://docs.python.org/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings).

Comment: ha rot13 ^^ I thought you needed separate imports rather than just calling it through the encode method.

Comment: Thanks! Is there any way to find the mimetype from the encoded image, or do I need to capture that from the stream?

Comment: Once you've decoded the data you can pass it to [`magic`](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-magic/) to detect the MIME type.

Comment: Advantage of using base64 module: no need to remove newlines, as they're never inserted in the first place; works with Python 3, which only allows byte-to-string codecs to be used with encode/decode